# Error:Broken Count>0 help? Can't download anything from software center.. Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, skype, lts

It says an error occured,please run package manager from right click menu or aptget in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was 'Error: Broken Count>0' This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

Last night I have been desperately trying to install skype and flash players but failed..
Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Launch Ubuntu Software Center and when it starts a window will pop telling you that there is an error etc. Press on repair.